# I see chinese characters when trying to read dvd content

Tags: directory, dvd, chinese

I am trying to read some CDs/DVDs written before 5-10 years in Windows environment. Folder names are in english but I see this screen.
Any help about what can cause this and how can I sort it out?

[image]

Comment: It's relatively simple (but unfortunately not obvious) to change the desired character encoding of file systems. The tricky part is figuring out what the correct character encoding is. For starters, what's the output of `grep -wF -e iso9960 -e udf /proc/mounts` (with the CD/DVD mounted) and what was the locale setting of the Windows installation that created the CD/DVD? What's the default locale of your Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Although I did not understand you, you helped me to focus on the right point.  LANG=en_US.UTF-8  is the locale in my installation, locale in windows was either english or greek. After downloading from language support (in System settings) some extra packages, it works correctly. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP solves the question and OP's comment made an answer.

> Although I did not understand you, you helped me to focus on the right point. `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` is the locale in my installation, locale in windows was either english or greek. After downloading from language support (in System settings) some extra packages, it works correctly. Thank you for help.

Comment: Well, that was rathermagical. Worked for me too - although I have no idea why exactly.

Comment: Can we get a few more details? Which packages were installed? Can we do this via a package manager?